# Take Column combination method in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am try to Find the combination of attributes values in my dataset:

```
0_1,2_2,0_1,0_1
2_2,0_1,0_1,3_3
2_2,3_3,2_2,3_3
2_2,2_2,2_2,3_3
0_1,3_3,2_2,0_1
3_3,0_1,0_1,0_1
```

Need to  take the count of each ranges in each Attribute:

Column : 0 Count : {2_2=2, 0_1=2, 3_3=1}

column : 1 Count : {2_2=2,0_1=2, 3_3=2}

Like these manner i have  to find combination of all attributes values:

From above example combination of column0 and column2 and its works fine,

but if we have data set with 75 columns loop until 75 , so GC  overhead limit exceeded with String builder
`(Column0,Column1)  :[0_12_2, 0_10_1]`

Can any one provide java code to take combination of all attributes without getting memory error.

Comment: Use a HashBag, loop through the rows for a certain column, add them to the HashBag, print. Then do it for the next column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to pretend your set is made up of `String`s and is stored in a `List<List<String>>` called `dataSet`.

You'd first want to determine how many columns there are. If the `List<List<String>>` is a list of rows and all of them have the same number of rows, then you'd just need the first one.

```
int columns = dataSet.get(0).size();
```

To count this stuff, I will be using a [`HashBag`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/bag/HashBag.html), which is an object you can get through the Apache Commons Collections library.

Next, just loop through:

```
for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
    for (List<String> list : dataSet) {
        Bag bag = new HashBag(); // I don't recall whether Apache Commons is generic
        bag.add(list.get(column));
        saveColumnStats(); // some method you would implement to save the data
    }
}
```

This is something of a broad overview, you'll need to change it to accommodate whatever methods or storage systems you are using.

The next part of the question, I literally do not understand, so I cannot provide you with any help on that. However, this part here should provide the data you need to start looking into this 'combination' algorithm that you are thinking of.

> Like these manner i have to find combination of attributes values:
>
> `(Column0,Column1)  :[0_12_2, 0_10_1]`
>
> Already tried with simple java code, but got GC memory overhead error
>   since my data set have 75 columns